# Eclipse Plugin: how to implement a new library type?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm implementing a Eclipse plugin but i have no knowledge for some point: how can I code my plugin to create in Eclipse another 'library type'.
  It's a common implementation: plugins like Maven and JUnit make it (there are several types, like: EAR libraries, JRE System library, Web App Library, etc...).
  I didn't find at eclipse framework documentation which API I must to use to 'register' my type. Any help 'll be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are looking for is called "classpath container". You will find resources if you search for that topic. Here is one tutorial to get you started.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-classpath/

Comment: Also, the reference for the extension point at http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_core_classpathContainerInitializer.html .